# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 in Android

Tags: java, android, jar, libraries, dalvik

I have big Android project with lots of packages and methods and i need to add some *.jar libraries into it. But when i do this i get an exception **"Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"**. 
I have read this article http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html but it doesn't help me. I have only *.jar libraries not java classes (as in article). I will be glad for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i know this. I have read some articles that explain how to solve this, but they all were about how to do this using java classes but not jar libraries.

Comment: Remove jars until you don't have too many methods.

Comment: I cant do this, because i heed this libs(((

Comment: How many libraries do you have?

Comment: You can sometimes find libraries that are made with the method limit in mind (e.g. https://github.com/square/wire ). Otherwise enable `proguard`, it can remove methods not actually used.

Comment: Kayaman, I have 20 jar libraries.  zapl, can you please give a link how to do that?

Comment: @zapl : i have enabled proguard. but still i get this error.